# Replce img src using Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, replace, hover, src

I am trying to change a part of img src upon hover using jquery (POST with MOBILE). Here is the html code

```
<a onclick="slideshow(7); return false;"href="http://example.com/12345">
<img src="https://DEF.com/123-post.jpg" width="200" heigh="200" class="fish" id="thumbnail_5">
</a>
```

and here is the jquery

```
$('a img').hover (function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace('post','mobile');
});
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong. Please help me out

Comment: try something like. First save the existing src string in a variable, then replace the required string then re-assign the changed string to the src property. Also to get set the property use `$(this).prop('src')` and `$(this).prop('src',myVar)` to set the property

Comment: Why you changed your first code? My code work correctly in snippet but if doesn't work for you check console for error. Also domain `DEF.com` isn't secure and browser doesn't download image from it that cause `hover` event doesn't fired for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should put new string in second parameter of [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of using it twice.

```
$('a img').hover(function(){
  this.src = this.src.replace('post', 'mobile');
});
```

```js
$('a img').hover(function(){
  this.src = this.src.replace('post', 'mobile');
  console.log(this.src);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com/12345">
  <img src="http://aDEF.com/123-post.jpg" width="200" heigh="200" class="fish" id="thumbnail_5">
</a>
```